# jQuery DataTables Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined but table is valid markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've been attempting to track this one down for a few weeks but without any joy. So far as I can tell my markup is valid, which is not the case for most posts about this on SO.

```
   <div class="container">
      <br />
      <div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>StudentId</th>
              <th>Group</th>
              <th>Student</th>
                <th>4</th>
                <th>1</th>
                <th>7</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>testgroup1</td>
                <td>Test Name2</td>
                  <td><input type="text" id="row-4-1a" name="row-4-1a" value="0"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" id="row-4-1b" name="row-4-1b" value="0"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" id="row-4-2" name="row-4-2" value="0"></td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <button id="mytestbutton" type="submit">Submit form</button>
    </div>
```

I have a C# backend that generates a lot of my content using Razor, but I've replicated the same behaviour using the source output from my browser. The JavaScript I'm using is as below, where I set some data into js objects from the backend ready to use, then initialise the DataTable on document ready.

```
var modelJson = JSON.parse('{"AssessmentId":1,"Name":"test1","Groups":[{"GroupId":1,"Name":"testgroup1","Students":[{"StudentId":4,"Name":"Test Name2","IsActive":true}],"StudentIds":[4],"IsActive":true}],"GroupIds":[1],"Questions":[{"QuestionId":0,"QuestionNumber":"1a","TopicDescription":"Topic goes here","AvailableMarks":4,"AssessmentId":0},{"QuestionId":0,"QuestionNumber":"1b","TopicDescription":"Topic goes here","AvailableMarks":1,"AssessmentId":0},{"QuestionId":0,"QuestionNumber":"2","TopicDescription":"Topic goes here","AvailableMarks":7,"AssessmentId":0}],"GradeBoundaries":{"A":80,"B":70,"C":0,"A*":90},"MarksAttained":[{"StudentId":4,"MarksAttained":{"1a":0,"1b":0,"2":0}}],"StudentIdsInAssessment":[4]}');
var columns = JSON.parse('[{"QuestionId":0,"QuestionNumber":"1a","TopicDescription":"Topic goes here","AvailableMarks":4,"AssessmentId":0},{"QuestionId":0,"QuestionNumber":"1b","TopicDescription":"Topic goes here","AvailableMarks":1,"AssessmentId":0},{"QuestionId":0,"QuestionNumber":"2","TopicDescription":"Topic goes here","AvailableMarks":7,"AssessmentId":0}]');

function InitialiseDataTable(e, t) {
  var a = [];
  e.forEach(function(e) {
    a.push({
      data: e.QuestionNumber,
      name: e.QuestionNumber,
      autoWidth: !0
    })
  }), $("#example").DataTable({
    processing: !0,
    serverSide: !1,
    filter: !1,
    orderMulti: !1,
    data: {
      test: 100
    },
    columnDefs: [{
      targets: [0],
      visible: !1,
      searchable: !1
    }],
    columns: a
  })
}
$("#mytestbutton").click(function() {
  var e = $("#example").$("input, select").serialize();
  return alert("The following data would have been submitted to the server: \n\n" + e.substr(0, 120) + "..."), !1
});

$(document).ready(() => {
  InitialiseDataTable(columns, 1);
});
```

This code is all running live on jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/w4q57hdu/ if you want to see the error in action.

I have been unable to determine why it's erroring where it is, I can only assume that there's something broken in the way I'm initialising the DataTable, but I can't see the wood for the trees. I loop through my columns object from the backend and use the QuestionNumber property from each in an array for initialising the DataTable.

It may be helpful to add that I followed the example at https://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html for this code.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few potential issues:

**1) The `columns` Option**

The `columns` data that you build contains a `data` option which is documented [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data). This expects to find the data for that column in an array containing objects of the given name.

So, for example, one of the values you push into the array is `"data": "1a"`.

This means DataTables expects the first column to get its data from the values named "1a" in the data source.

**2) The `data` Option**

The `data` option (see [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/data)) tells DataTables where to look for the table data. For example, it's used by the above `columns.data` option. This option is supposed to contain an array of arrays, or an array of objects. It also needs to be valid JSON. In your case, it is just this: `data: { test: 100 }`. This is not valid JSON.

This also does not support the `columns.data` names expected (e.g. "1a" as noted above).

**3) The HTML Table**

DataTables also lets you define your data directly in the HTML table - which you have done here. This conflicts with using the `data` option, too.

**A Quick Test**

Comment out the `data:...` and `columns:...` options in your DataTable definition. You will no longer get any errors. This is just a quick way to confirm the above notes.

If you are providing all your data directly into the HTML table before initializing your DataTable object, then that may be all you need (like the example you are following).

**One Way Forward**

If you want to pass both the data and column definitions dynamically to DataTables via JSON (which I assume you do) then you can to do the following:

a) Strip down the HTML table by removing all its inner tags (`<thead>`, `<tbody>`). You will avoid your current conflicts by having an [empty HTML table definition](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html).

b) Provide column headings in the `a.push` section by using `title: e.QuestionNumber,` (or whatever field you want to use for headings). See [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title).

c) Use a function to build the input fields you need for the relevant column values. You need to do this because you no longer have these in the `<html>` definition.

For step (c), you can see an example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/data_rendering.html) of how to dynamically render different types of data in your cell using `render: function(...)`.

That should give you some pointers.

It may not get you to your end goal - but you should be able to move past your current error, and ask a more specific/targeted question, as needed (assuming it has not already been asked and answered here, of course).